# Deploying a Phoenix app to Heroku using CloudFlare

Tags: heroku, dns, elixir, phoenix-framework, cloudflare

I started developing my personal blog (and a basic CMS) using Phoenix.

I successfully deployed it to Heroku following the Documentation/Guides, [it's live](http://jonathansoifer.herokuapp.com).

Now I added my custom domain "[jonathansoifer.com](http://jonathansoifer.com)" to the Heroku App but everytime I access it, the URL on the browser switches from that custom domain to the "Heroku app URL" (jonathansoifer.herokuapp.com).

Am I missing something?

It might be useful to know that the DNS is being managed by CloudFlare, using CNAME flattening as recommended by CloudFlare itself.

CNAME • jonathansoifer.com • jonathansoifer.com.herokudns.com

Comment: this is going to be a difficult question to answer because you'll probably need to post more info.  However, the first thing I noticed is that when I ping `jonathansoifer.com` it returns the following IP address, `104.24.107.212`  And if ping `https://jonathansoifer.herokuapp.com/` it returns `54.225.240.148` So somewhere your DNS is jacked up :/

Comment: @Chris what additional info would you like me to post?

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, the issue was within `config/prod.exs`.

I had hard coded the Heroku URL there in order to take advantage of Heroku's free SSL when using their subdomains.

Comment: Can you tell me how you fixed this? @jaysoifer